# Battleships game, ships drowned in C

Tags: c, drawing, 2d-games, coordinate-systems

I'm making a "battleships" game, and after placing all the ships, starting the game, etc., the user will enter "coordinates to attack" and if he hits a ship then the board will show 'V' in the coordinate the he hit and 'X' if there weren't any ships there.

Well I did that part and its not the problem here, I have 4 different ships each with a different size, to drown the ship you have to hit all of its parts (its size).

Example:

```
4|*
3|  *
2|    *
1|
0|* * * *
  - - - - -
  0 1 2 3 4
Enter coordinates for attack
(0,4)

4|V
3|  *
2|    *
1|
0|* * * *
  - - - - -
  0 1 2 3 4
Enter coordinates for attack
(1,3)

4|V
3|  V
2|    *
1|
0|* * * *
  - - - - -
  0 1 2 3 4
Enter coordinates for attack
(2,2)

4|V
3|  V
2|    V
1|
0|* * * *
  - - - - -
  0 1 2 3 4

the battleship of size 3 has drowned!
```

And if the 4 battleships are drowned then its game over! What I did is to check
all of the ship coordinates are 'V' and if so the the battleship has drowned but I think my problem is that there are more than one ship and if I check this every time it'll always say the the first battleship has drowned.

I made two arrays that contain the locations of the ships:

```
posX[] = {1,2,3,4}
posY[] = {1,2,3,4}
```

<sup>(means the ship is on the locations (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) the size is 4.)</sup>

What I did was like this:

```
for (int i = 0 l i < 4 ; i++)
{
if (board[posX[i]][posY[i] == 'V')
{
count++;
}
}
if ( count == 4 ) printf("the battleship of size 4 has drowned\n");
```

And I tried something familiar to check if all the coordinates are 'V' the printf, but it's the same.

Comment: Best is if you could provide your code in the question too

Comment: It's absolutely impossible to say what could be wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @lan i edited the post i'll be happy if you could check it out

Answer (score 1):

you need to maintain a status for each of the battleships, like isDead[4] or such. init to 0. Once a battleship is declared dead you notify it's dead, change the status to 1 and stop checking for it later

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you don't need to always be checking that. If every time the player hits a ship, you check if the ship is drowned (all its coordinates were hit), you just need to increment a counter of drowned_ships and check if that value is already equal to the stop/termination condition (drowned_ships == 4).

```
#define DROWNED_SHIPS_STOP 4

bool ship::isDrowned(){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size() ; i++){
        //size() here would return 4 for your example -> it is the size of the ship
        if (board[posX[i]][posY[i] == 'V'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return (count == size()) ? true:false;
}

(...)

//Receive a x and y
coordinates = get_player_input();

Ship * ship;
if (ship = isShip(coordinates.x,coordinates.y)){
    //test if a ship has been hit
    if( ship.isDrowned() ){
        //every position of that ship has been hit
        ships_drowned++;
        if (ships_drowned == DROWNED_SHIPS_STOP)
            DisplayGameTermination();
    } 
}
```